# How to find the transfer function of this digital controller and DC Motor?

Tags: motor, dc-motor, control, motor-controller

I am studying digital control theory and struggling with a particular diagram of a digital control system. The system is presented below:

[image: block diagram with two nested feedback loops]

\$D(z)\$ is a digital compensator, \$G_{h0}\$ is a zero order hold circuit with adjustable gain \$k_2\$. The blocks \$G_{p1}\$ and \$G_{p2}\$ are part of the DC motor model. The sampling time is \$0.1\$s.

Given the motor parameters, \$G_{p1}\$ is found to be:

$$ G_{p1}(s) = \frac{K_t}{JLs^2 + (JR+bL)s +bR + K_e K_t} $$

and \$G_{p2}\$:

$$G_{p2}(s) = \frac{1}{s} $$

My question is about the \$T\$ symbol in the feedback loop. Should this be included in some way in the feedback loop when calculating the transfer function? For example, below I present my code to find the transfer function of the following system.

```matlab
    % DC motor constants
    J=0.01; % Rotor momentum of inertia
    b=0.01; % viscous friction
    kt=0.01; % torque constant
    ke=0.01; % electromotive force constant
    k2 = 1; % ZOH gain
    R=1;    % rotor resistance
    L=0.5;  % inductor resistance
    T = 0.1; % sampling time
    s = tf('s');
    z = tf('z');

    gho = (1-exp(-T*s))/s;

    % Transfer Function
    num=kt*k2; 
    den=[J*L J*R+b*L b*R+ke*kt];
    disp('Open loop Transfer function velocity control without controller')
    TF_DC_vel=tf(num,den)

    disp('Clsoed loop Transfer function velocity control without controller')
    TF_DC_vel_closed = feedback(TF_DC_vel, 1) . % <---- Should this be 1 or 0.1?
```

Output:

```
Open loop Transfer function velocity control without controller

TF_DC_vel =

              0.01
  ----------------------------
  0.005 s^2 + 0.015 s + 0.0101

Continuous-time transfer function.

Clsoed loop Transfer function velocity control without controller

TF_DC_vel_closed =

              0.01
  ----------------------------
  0.005 s^2 + 0.015 s + 0.0201
```

Converting to Z-domain:

```matlab
% Z Transfer Function
disp('Z Domain, Open loop, Velocity Control, Transfer Function without controller')
tf_z_open_vel = c2d(TF_DC_vel,0.1)

% Z Transfer Function
disp('Z Domain, Closed loop, Velocity Control, Transfer Function without controller')
tf_z_closed_vel = feedback(tf_z_open_vel,1)
```

Output:

```
Z Domain, Open loop, Velocity Control, Transfer Function without controller

tf_z_open_vel =

  0.009056 z + 0.008194
  ----------------------
  z^2 - 1.723 z + 0.7408

Sample time: 0.1 seconds
Discrete-time transfer function.

Z Domain, Closed loop, Velocity Control, Transfer Function without controller

tf_z_closed_vel =

  0.009056 z + 0.008194
  ---------------------
  z^2 - 1.714 z + 0.749

Sample time: 0.1 seconds
Discrete-time transfer function.
```

More specifically, should the feedback be 1 or 0.1? 1 refers to the normal feedback if nothing was present in the feedback loop while 0.1 would be the sampling time.

I am uncertain which it should be and why. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: is the lower case \$ j\$ in the equations the moment of inertia \$ J\$ ?

Comment: Thank you for the useful edit. Yes that should be a capital \$J\$ for moment of inertia. Will correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should be -1 in both cases, because it refers to a **negative feedback** being unitary

```matlab
TF_DC_vel_closed = feedback(TF_DC_vel, -1)
```

The \$ T \$ means the sampling period, so, every \$ T\$ seconds the system gets new sensor measurements and updates its output \$u(t)\$.

Also, notice that you have not used at all `gho`.

I would suggest discretizing \$G_{p1}\$ with \$T=0.1\$s . Then doing the feedback(\$k_2 G_{h0} G_{p1} \$) = \$ \hat{G}\$.
Then do the feedback(\$ D(z) \hat{G} G_{p2}\$). That would properly combine the system blocks.

Comment: Small question about the outer feedback loop:  \$G_p2\$ should be \$z/(z-1)\$ or \$1/(z-1)\$?

Comment: use the `c2d` function on matlab, you can look at https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ug/continuous-discrete-conversion-methods.html for a small description of each method. as a rule of thumb, ZOH if your system behaves slower than your sampling, Tustin (bilinear approximation) for systems that are close to or faster than your sampling.

Comment: notice the main difference between \$ z/(z−1)\$ and \$1/(z−1)\$ is that the first has an extra lead (inverse of the delay) They will be very similar.